# Required to release connection when using PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager

Tags: rest, http, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

According to definition, PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager reuses the connections. If so

1) It is not needed to explicitly release the connection after?

2) Manager won't be able to reuse connection if released?

```
executing a method?

CloseableHttpClient closableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(getPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()).build();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(resourcePath);                    
                try {
                    return closableHttpClient.execute(post);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                   //handle exception
                }finally {
                    post.releaseConnection();
                }
```

Comment: Closing the `CloseableHttpReponse` ultimately closes the connection. What you may be trying to do (based on your previous post) is execute pooling in a mutlithreaded way. See [**Threaded Request Execution example**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientMultiThreadedExecution.java), with other example found [**here**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html). Also more explanation found [**here in section 2.4**](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e380)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) It is. Connection manager has no way of knowing whether or not the application layer is done reading from a leased connection. Therefore, it must be explicitly released back to the manager

(2) Whether or not a connection can be re-used depends on several factors: response message must be fully consumed, both ends (client and server) must signal their intent to keep the connection alive, no i/o errors, etc

Comment: https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientConnectionRelease.java says that connection is released back to the pool as soon as after closing inputstream. Some people have commented that its released on response.close(), and many examples support this. But javadocs of HttpResponseProxy.close() says "Releases the connection without the option of keep-alive. This is a hard release that implies a shutdown of the connection. Use releaseConnection() for a graceful release." Is there any worthy reference to confirm what is correct?

Comment: Both statements are correct. If the response entity is fully consumed _prior_ to a call to CloseableHttpResponse#close the underlying connection gets returned back to the connection manager in a consistent, re-usable state. The subsequent call to #close has no effect.

Comment: Okay, but HttpResponseProxy.close() code calls this.connHolder.abortConnection() if (this.connHolder != null), does this check makes sure, such that the connHolder is guaranteed to become null before calling close, if response entity is fully consumed? Also can you please point me to the class where this trigger fires on inputstream closure?

Comment: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/xref/org/apache/http/conn/EofSensorInputStream.html

Comment: Thanks, this clears some things, but how does it tie up with HttpResponseProxy.close and this.connHolder != null

Comment: Just to clarify your question: ConnectionHolder#releaseConnection first checks whether it is already released. This is done by the ResponseEntityProxy class when the eof or close is detected.
see: https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/ConnectionHolder.java#L95 and https://github.com/apache/httpcomponents-client/blob/4.5.x/httpclient/src/main/java/org/apache/http/impl/execchain/ResponseEntityProxy.java#L115

Answer (score 5):

typical use case is :

```
CloseableHttpClient closableHttpClient = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(getPoolingHttpClientConnectionManager()).build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
try {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        try {
            // do something useful
        } finally {
            instream.close();
        }
    }
} finally {
    response.close();
}
```

1. It is. *instream.close()* and *response.close()* will trigger the explicitly release underlying connection.Here so called release does not close socket directly. It will check several facts:
   1) if the stream is full consumed
   2) if the connection is set reused
   3) if peer server response with keep alive
2. *closableHttpClient.close()* will shut down the connection pool

Comment: Nice shoutout on the fact that `CloseableHttpClient.close()` will shutdown the **connection pool**.  I was using a "try with resource" statement, and noticed that my connection pool was in a shutdown state afterward.  To me it seems odd that closing a **client** would shutdown the **manager**.  All the same, thanks for verifying that I won't incur any memory leaks by not closing the client.